# `fs.mkdir` is creating the directory with different permissions than those specified

Tags: node.js, unix, permissions, fs

Due to the modules my node program uses, it requires root to run.  This is because it has to run a HTTP server on port 80 (and as you know, lower ports like that require root in order to be used).

But, this program also uses a `fs` method to create a file.  I don't mind if root is the owner as long as I can change the permissions...  But that's exactly where I'm hitting the bump.

I'm using the `fs.mkdir` function to create a directory like so:

(Lets say this file is named `create.js`)

```
fs.mkdir(__dirname + "/.loud", 0777, function(err){
  if (err) console.log("Failed to create file at " + __dirname + "/.loud");
});
```

When executing it (Remember, via sudo, `sudo node create.js`) it does in fact create the folder...  But the permissions provided (`0777`) are wrong!...

If I'm not mistaken, `7` implies read, write, and execute.  Using it for the 3 fields (`777` + a leading `0` to represent it as an octal) should imply that everyone can read, write, and execute inside this folder...  But here is what I get when checking the folder's permissions:

```
[imac] jamen : ~/Tests/mkdir $ ls -a -l .
...
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  root  4096 Jun 12 22:27 .loud
```

So, lets seperate the beginning permissions part:

```
d, rwx, r-x, r-x
```

So, I don't know what the `d` means (feel free to tell me in the comments), so I think we can throw that out.   Here is what the other  means:

1. The owner can read, write, and execute (as expected)
2. The group can read, and execute (What?! We specified `7`, meaning it should also be able to write???)
3. Everyone else can read, and execute (Again...  We also specified `7`, should everyone also be able to write?)

So, in attempt to solve, I went on a venture and [found this post on SE.Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103413/is-there-any-difference-between-mode-value-0777-and-777), and after reading it, I thought I might as well try to specify the permissions in decimal format, instead of octal format...

Here is how I changed our `create.js` file:

```
fs.mkdir(__dirname + "/.loud", 511, function(err){
  if (err) console.log("Failed to create file at " + __dirname + "/.loud");
});
```

(Since 0777 in octal is represented as 511 in decimal)

But, this unfortunately gives the same exact results (yes, I did delete the folder before running this again, otherwise NodeJS would have passed an error in the callback):

```
[imac] jamen : ~/Tests/mkdir $ ls -a -l .
...
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  root  4096 Jun 12 22:35 .loud
```

Am I misunderstanding something about Unix's permissions scheme, or am I making a mistake in NodeJS?

How would I fix this so the folder gets the permissions `0777`, implying the owner as rwx permissoins, the group has rwx permissoins, and everyone else has rwx permissions...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it applies [umask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) on your mode. Type `umask` in your console, you will see 022 or 0022.

You can overwrite it for your node process with `process.umask(newmask);`

Comment: So, in this case I'd want to do `process.umask(0)`? Because I read that umask act's somewhat like this (or at least in my scenario): 0777 - 0022 = 0755...?

Comment: Exactly, it's a binary and that's applied

Comment: One more question, do you think it'd be wise to have the umask in the code itself (like you provided with the `process.umask`), or  have that depend on the user of the library? (e.g. they'd have to set the umask themselves in their `~/.bashrc` or somewhere)

Comment: You should not change a global variable in your library. It's up to the user to take those responsibilities.

Comment: I really don't understand what this answer is saying