# Do I need to set folder permissions in node.js Express?

Tags: node.js, express, chmod

I'm learning Express, but none of the tutorials I read mention anything about folder permissions. Is it necessary to set folder permissions when developing websites with Express?

I created some websites in the past using Apache and PHP, it was always very important to set the right permissions. Right now I'm serving static content (HTML uses Vue and fetches data through an API), but Express can create new folders and read/write files. Should I worry about `0777` permissions? (Ubuntu server)

**EDIT**: a heads-up for anyone who's trying this, [make sure to understand umask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30815154/fs-mkdir-is-creating-the-directory-with-different-permissions-than-those-speci), otherwise you'll write the wrong permissions (for example, `0777` will become `0755`)

Comment: Folder permissions are mentioned with fs functions in node. They have little to do with node and everything to do with your OS. So yes the node process needs to have permission to read/write/execute.

Comment: @Dominik Thanks! But can the user access the folder if there's no route for it in Express? (e.g., `app.get('/hiddenfolder/' ...`

Comment: There is no folder listing in express. You would have to write a function that reads a directory and then return that in your route

Comment: @Dominik Great! So the user can't access that folder anyway?  (i.e., unless I write a function)

Comment: You should put express behind a proxy (nginx proxy or whatever floats your boat) anyway.

Comment: Thanks! I should also have clarified that by "user" I meant an intruder, someone that shouldn't have access to that, but you've solved my question